# traefik with docker and multiple mysql containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have several laravel projects on my local machine, all are run with docker-compose. All projects are in the same docker network.
In the docker-compose.yml files I always define an explicit MySQL Port for the database service, so that I can use all projects simultanously. Meaning, I always write something like this in the docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
  - 3307:3306
```

So every database has its own port on my machine, like 3308, 3309 and so on.
Problem is, upon sharing those projects with other developers, everyone has to define his or her own docker-compose.yml with different ports than on my machine.

Now my question is, can I use traefik to route every request on port 3306 to the correct container?

I'd like to write `3306:3306` in every project without having to define explicit ports for every MySQL service.

Is that possible at all?

If not, how can such thing be achieved?

Comment: `to the correct container?` Which one is "correct"?

Comment: I basically want to achieve the same thing I do with port 80. Meaning, every request on my host machine that goes to port 80 is redirect via a nginx reverse proxy to the "correct" container. The correct container ist recognized by a virtual hostname I have set.
With port 3306 I'd like to do the same thing if that is possible at all. I thought maybe traefik could be able to do that.

Comment: Yea, but you can't. It's not "port 80", its http _protocol_ allows to send domain name when creating request. Mysql protocol does not have that.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to solve services with dynamic ip and port, is implementing service catalog.

You can go big, and install consul (and nomad) and register the location of your services in consul (or run it from nomad and get dynamic port with consul integration). Then, you would use [rfc 2782](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/services/discovery/dns-static-lookups#rfc-2782-lookup) lookup [from mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-dns-srv.html) to comnect to proper ip and port of the service.

You could also slap your own solution - write a script that scan running mysql docker containers on a machine and filters the one woth proper tags and returns the ip and port it listens to.

Or you can just use a file with columns: name, ip and port, and put that file on a shared nfs that you share with others.

Or anything between.

Http *protocol* transfers domain name as part of the protocol. That is not possible with mysql protocol.